# Automate Release Notes using Jenkins and Github

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build that will create a pre-release with a tag and then upload an artifact. To add to this I would also like to create some basic release notes, so for now all the feature branches that have been created/merged into master since the last tag.

### Update

I have found `git log --oneline --decorate` but can I just get the logs from the last tag? so the commits between tag `13.4.0` and `13.4.9` as an example

I guess then after that I will need to parse the results into an array which I can then extract what I want from.

Comment: How about using https://github.com/MartinSeeler/auto-changelog-hook/blob/master/post-commit as a git hook to your repository? Have you tried using this apporach?

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress over the weekend and thought I would share, though any improvement pointers are welcome, as I'm sure this could be done a better way.

So to start with I needed to get all the commits from the previous tag up until the current version of master

```
 // Get Commits
 def commits = sh script: """ git log ${previous_tag}..HEAD --oneline --decorate""", returnStdout: true
 def array = commits.split("\\n");
```

Then I needed to pull out all the commits with a particular identifier (something we do)

```
// Declare array and get all commits starting with STRING1|string1
ArrayList<String> mycommits = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
 for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w{7}\\s(STRING1-|string1-)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(array[i]);
   if(matcher.find()) {
     mycommits.add(array[i]) 
   }
 }
```

Then as commit messages could be duplicated or the identifier used more than once on a particular story I created a HashSet which would make sure only unique values are stored (stripping out all duplications)

```
// Put all unique mycommits matches into a set
 Set<String> mycommits_set = new HashSet<String>(mycommits.size());
 for(int i =0; i < mycommits.size(); i++) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(STRING1-|string1-)\\w+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mycommits[i]);
   if(matcher.find()) {
     String id = matcher.group().toUpperCase();
     mycommits_set.add("[" + id + "](https://jira.dev.organisaiton.co.uk/browse/" + id + ")");
   }
 }
```

Then finally back to a ArrayList so I can iterate through

```
// Unique results back to List object
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(mycommits_set);
 String listString = "";
 for (String s : list)
 {
   listString += s + "\\n";
 }
```

This returns the following as a String (reduced to two to save listing more)

```
"[STRING1-2150](https://jira.dev.organisation.co.uk/browse/STRING1-2150)
 [STRING1-2151](https://jira.dev.organisation.co.uk/browse/STRING1-2151)
 "
```

Comment: where is Jenkins in all of that?